# CN field is missing in SSL certificate from subject

Tags: ssl

I have SSL certificate, and I want to know the domain name associated with the certificate, for that I am using openssl to get the text of the `.crt` file.

The sample output is as follows:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Serial Number: 87778 (22)
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=IN, ST=Maharastra, L=Mumbai, O=Tests Pvt Ltd, OU=test/emailAddress=all@test.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Jan  2 02:09:10 2014 GMT
        Not After : Dec 31 02:09:10 2023 GMT
    Subject: C=IN, ST=Maharastra, L=Mumbai, O=Tests Pvt Ltd, OU=test/emailAddress=all@test.com
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
```

As we can see there is not `CN` field in the above certificate, let me know if the certificate is wrong, or we can expect certificate files without CN.

Comment: Most browsers would mark this certificate as "unsafe" when being produced by a server because the CN does not match the server URL, but AFAIK the CN is not mandatory per se. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55414/is-the-common-name-mandatory-for-digital-certificates

Answer (score 2):

With HTTPS a server certificate is expected to contain the name of the server and this name should match the expected name, otherwise the TLS handshake will fail. The name is specified today using the Subject Alternative Names (SAN) extension and before that was given using the CN of the subject. But the CN is considered obsolete for years and browsers like Chrome will not consider it anymore, i.e. make the SAN mandatory.

The certificate in your case contains neither CN nor SAN and thus will not be usable for HTTPS. There are other use cases of SSL/TLS apart from HTTPS though where this certificate might be acceptable. But it is unclear what specific use case you have.

Comment: It turned out it is an self signed certificate

Comment: @Bidyut: Even a self-signed certificate can have CN and/or SAN. But this is also an old X509v1 instead of the more modern X509v3 certificate. Thus it cannot even have extensions like SAN.

Comment: I guess while creating, we did not give the CN.